# Basic LINQ To Object query

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

LINQ: Typing my first ever LINQ query and the system is not recognizing my code line which is as follows:

```
int[] i= { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; 
IEnumerable<int> j = from r in i select r;
```

My "i" bears red squiggly saying - a field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field method or property

Comment: Where are you writing this code that matters

Comment: @svik Post your full method.

Comment: What sense does this code make? Why not simply `i.AsEnumerable()`?

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad, You guessed it right. The Place I was writing my code in,was not right. The Code in itself is absolutely right though. There is no problem with this line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field method or
>   property

This error means you're trying to initialize your `IEnumerable<T>` inside a `class` level declaration with a LINQ query. If you want to initialize that field, do so inside the class constructor:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    int[] I = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; 
    IEnumerable<int> J { get; set; }

    public SomeClass()
    {
        J = from r in i select r;
    }
}
```